# Why Hanuman became staunch devotee of Lord Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman

I know Lord Shiva showed his love towards Lord Vishnu by incarnating as Hanuman during Rama Avatar. But Hanuman didn't know he was incarnation of Shiva/ Vayu. (i think he still doesn't know it).

I read Hanuman's first meeting with Rama but i didn't find any reason why Hanuman became ardent devotee of Lord Rama. Lord Hanuman always chants name of Rama.

- Can anyone explain the reason behind his devotion to Rama?
- Did Hanuman know that Rama was avatar of Vishnu?

**Note:** Shiva Purana says Hanuman is devotee of Rama.

The Chapter [**Incarnation of Hanumat**" in "**Satarudrasamhita**" of **Shiva Purana**](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/4/Chapter2_1149-1228p.pdf)" (Pg No- 1154) says " ***Himself a leader of devotees, he made Rama and Sita happy. He, Lord of Monkeys, established cult of devotion to Rama in the World***". Shiva Purana says Hanuman was born for Rama's work. No specific reason was mentioned for his devotion.

Comment: Hanuman doesn't know he is incarnation of Shiva, but Shiva knows he is in Hanuman. This question arised in your mind because you think Hanuman and Shiva are different. Hanuman exists because of Shiva. Shiva is the essence of Hanuman.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria yeah Hanuman is incarnation of Shiva. But  Hanuman doesn't know he is Shiva. It's not like Vishnu incarnated as Krishna where Krishna knew that he was Vishnu. Krishna was aware that he was God and knew about his Self. But without realizing or knowing about his Self or the reason for which he was created, Hanuman became devotee of Rama. It was not mutual benefits ( as a Vanara and Rama) that Hanuman sought but he developed devotion ( Bhakti). And there are no reasons or references for FRIENDSHIP which resorted to DEVOTION.

Comment: Hanuman doesn't need to know Shiva because Hanuman = Shiva and Shiva = Shiva and Shiva came to earth just to help Vishnu and he decided to become Vishnu's bhakt.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria You cannot say simply Shiva decided.There should be cause for any action in this cosmos.There should be cause/reason in Hanuman's reality for his devotion.

Comment: Shiva is in Vishnu's heart and Vishnu is in Shiva's heart. They both have infinite respect for each other. Both worship each other.

Comment: There should be some story for their lila. Without story how lila can happen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30590/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-chinmay-sarupria).

Comment: It is not 100% clear that Hanuman is an incarnation of Shiva. It is false to conclude this.

Comment: Hanuman is Avatar of Vayu he is not avatars of siva he knows that he is a avatara of Vayu

Answer (score 4):

According to Ramgiri Braun (student of Neemkaroli Baba, aka Laxman Das),

> Hanuman, the great monkey God of the Ramayana is a symbol of the mind that has become disciplined and filled with devotion. Hanuman is the evolved state of our unruly monkey mind that constantly jumps from thought to thought. This mind is fully focused on the presence of the Divine Self, the Lord of Life within the heart.
>
> When Rama asks Hanuman, “How do you look upon me?” the great monkey gives a three-part answer, **“When I believe I am the body, then I am your faithful servant. When I know I am the soul, I know myself to be a spark of your eternal Light. And when I have the vision of truth, you and I, my Lord, are one and the same.”**
>
> With this answer, he shows us three states we flow through in our spiritual quest. **Many times we identify with the person, the body-mind–ego we think we are. At those times we can realize that we are here to do God’s work**, to serve that higher Self in us and in everything. This is the foundation of **Karma Yoga**, the yoga of service.
>
> One level up and we realize we are not as separate from divine intelligence as we thought, that there is a higher knowing and presence working through us. **We sense we are not separate from other beings and that our existence is an expression of the indescribable presence of God in us.** This is where **Bhakti and Raja Yoga** open us further.
>
> The most dramatic shift in our perception occurs when all veils lift and we have the vision of truth. **Then we know that we are all that exists. We are the Source; we are One. Jnana Yoga** aims at this direct perception.
>
> What allows Hanuman to have this complete vision? It is faith (Shraddha). This faith is the origin of five essential levels of spiritual practice. **Hanuman is, therefore, the manifestation of faith that gives us strength, which transforms our memory and leads us through samadhi to perfect wisdom.**
> …
> (Faith) is based on the direct experience of Truth and therefore more solid than a rock. For those on the devotional path **faith is born out of love and love grows our faith.**

Hanuman experienced truth in Rama and thus gained endless faith and endless devotion. He continues,

> This faith gives us strength (Virya) and allows us to remain increasingly unshaken in the ups and downs of life.
> …
> As our strength grows, it evolves our memory (Smriti). **Realizing the crucial importance of our spiritual practice, our commitment becomes increasingly stable and we approach a state of continuous remembrance of our Source.**
> …
> Vyasa tells us that the awareness that we are constantly loved by the Divine, is the greatest force that allows us to surrender spontaneously to the inner Source. We realize what we have been seeking is what we are.

So, upon seeing Rama, Hanuman remembered that Rama is Viṣnu and that he himself is Shiva. This further increased Hanuman's love for Rama. With such love & awareness also comes the understanding that both are as One.

> Focused on the Divine presence within **we realize we are the giver and receiver of love—the lover and the beloved**—in one. This is the blossoming of perfect wisdom (prajna), the clear perception of the enlightened state. We discover we are all that exists. **We are one appearing as many and able to give ourselves fully to love** because we realize there is no possibility to be hurt in this inner union.

---

### TL;DR

Upon seeing Rama's glory, Hanuman instantly felt faith in & love for Rama. These lead Hanuman to remember what he had forgotten: Rama *is* Viṣnu & Hanuman *is* Śiva and they are One. This realization further multiplied his love & devotion.

---

Answer (score 2):

Sri Hanuman was not the devotee of Sri Rama, as commonly believed.

Sri Hanuman appears first in Kishkinda Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana, when he meets Sri Rama and Lakshmana.  By the time he met Sri Rama, he had already mastered 3 Vedas, acquired Siddhis, had enormous strength.

Further, Sage Valmiki did not describe him to be a devotee of Sri Rama.  However, Sage Valmiki described him to have served Sugriva as well as Sri Rama.

So can we conclude that Sri Hanuman is the devotee of Sugriva as well?  No.

Let us consider the following issues.

---

In Ramayana, Sage Valmiki describes Sri Hanuma as the follower of Dakshinachara, the follower of Vedic way life..

> अञ्जलिं प्राङ्मुखः कृत्वा पवनायात्मयोओनयो |
>
> ततो हि ववृधे गन्तुं दक्षिणो दक्षिणां दिश्म् ||
>
> (Sundara Kanda 1 Sarga 9 sloka)

---

Sage Valmiki used the words दक्षिणो दक्षिणां दिश्म् in the sloka. If the words दक्षिणां दिश्म् indicate Southern Direction, why did the sage used the word दक्षिणो (Dakshino) again?

The word दक्षिणो (Dakshino) was used to indicate that Sri Hanuma is the follower of DAKSHINAACHARA, i.e., the VEDIC way life. Sri Hanuma was described by the Sage Valmiki as expert in all Vedas.

Sri Rama, Lakshmana, Sugriva, King Dasaratha, King Janaka, Sage Agasthya, etc, were also  the followers of Vedic way life.

It is very surprising to note that in the entire Srimad Ramayana, Sage Valmiki describes Sri Hanuman alone as he **follower of Dakshinachara**.

---

Sri Hanuman was a learned person, carried enormous strength, exhibited Super Human Powers, apart from being a Realised Soul.

Sage Valmiki presented Sri Hanuman as the representative of Dakshinachara, whereas Ravana and Indrajit was presented as the representatives of Vamachara.

---

After going through "Sundara Kanda" many times, I realised that Seeta understood the strength of Sri Hanuman.

> कामम् अस्य त्वम् एव एकः कार्यस्य परिसाधने | पर्याप्तः पर वीरघ्न यशस्यः
> ते बल उदयः ||
>
> "O Hanuma, the annihilator of enemies! You are yourself surely
> sufficient single-handed completion of this task. Your elevated energy
> is creditable indeed."

However, Seeta did not want Sri Hanuman to take her to her husband.  Her husband has to fight the battle, win the battle and get her released from the custody of Ravana.

> शरैस्तुः सम्कुलाम् कृत्वा लन्काम् पर बल अर्दनः | माम् नयेत् यदि
> काकुत्स्थः तस्य तत् सादृशम् भवेत् ||
>
> "But, it will be appropriate for Rama, who destroys the hostile
> forces, to take me with him, after routing Lanka with his arrows."
>
> तत् यथा तस्य विक्रान्तम् अनुरूपम् महात्मनः | भवति आहव शूरस्य तत्त्वम्
> एव उपपादय ||  (Sundara Kanda 56 Sarga 3-5 Slokas)

Hence, Sita asked Sri Hanuma to act in such a way that Sri Rama comes down to Lanka, fights the battle, eliminates Ravana alongwith his relatives, and gets the fame of taking her alongwith him to Ayodhya.

"Therefore, you act in such a way that the high-souled Rama, valiant in battle, may exhibit prowess worthy of him."

---

1. Sri Hanuman did not propose to carry the entire vanara army over ocean to reach Lanka.  He simply said to Sri Rama that find a way to reach Lanka.  It is for Sri Rama to find a way.
2. Sri Hanuman remain captivated with the usage of brahmAstra by Indrajit, only to honour **brahma, the pitAmaha**.  We have to remember that brahmAstra cannot arrest him for more than a little time.

> प्रसादिते च पवने ब्रह्मा तुभ्यम् वरम् ददौ | अशस्त्र वध्यताम् तात समरे
> सत्य विक्रम || ४-६६-२७
>
> "Oh, chivalric warrior at war, while the Air-god is being supplicated,
> oh, dear boy, Brahma gave you a boon decreeing your 'indestructibility
> by any missile...'

3. Sri Hanuman did not try to stop, though being capable, Indrajit when he was attacking, staying invisible by using his ascetic powers,  Sri Rama and Lakshmana.

If he intervenes, their glory diminishes and ego gets hurt. Sri Rama and Lakshmana had to toil.  After all it was their battle.  He helped them by remaining in sidelines.

4. Another question arises as to why Sri Hanuman helped Sugriva as well as Sri Rama in accomplishing their tasks, being a Realised Soul.  Instead he can sit at a place silently and engrossed in deep contemplation, being a Jnani.

Sri Hanuman, being a Realised Soul, ***did not need a kingdom, or fame or followers***, etc, **to show off his valour**.  Being a Realised Soul, it was his topmost priority to see that **the ordinary people/vanaras have a good king, to follow.**

Ordinary people may venerate a Jnani, but follow a righteous King.  It is the King, who exemplary life becomes a role model for ordinary people.

**Righteous Kings like Sri Rama and Sugriva can do that**.  That was Why Sri Hanuman, being a Realised Soul, who wished the happiness to all people, served those righteous kings.

---

It was in subsequent puranas or other Ramayanas that depicted Sri Hanuman to be a devotee of Sri Rama.

Comment: Thanks for your satirical praise:-).  You can elaborate your comment, so that I can understand you have in your mind @Prasanna

Comment: //If he intervenes, their glory diminishes and ego gets hurt.// who are you referring to as he and their ?

Comment: It was mentioned in the next sentence.  He means Sri Hanuman and they means Sri Rama and Lakshmana. @Satya

Comment: Woah! Are you sure that even if Hanuman did everything, their glory diminishes and their ego hurts ? After all, can there be any human even close to Rama? It is what you think after all. It is you attributing that non existent ego damage to Rama. That may be true since ignorant people like me cannot understand such things. Or jnanis like you may know everything.

Comment: That same self realised Hanuman words goes as follows :                           .ब्रह्म स्वयमुभूश्च तुराननो वा |
रुद्रस्त्रिणेत्रस्त्रिपुरान्तको वा |
इन्द्रो महेन्द्रः सुरनायको वा |
त्रातुम् न शक्ता युधि रामवध्यम् || ५-५१-४५.                                                       . If you think either Sundara khanda or this verse as an interpolation. Then ignore this.

Comment: In yuddha kanda, Hanuman's devotion to Lakshmana (and by implication Rama) is mentioned. Lakshmana falls unconscious in the middle of battle. Ravana is unable to lift him. But Hanuman is able to lift Lakshmana due to his devotion.

Comment: वायुसूनोः सुहृत्त्वेन भक्त्या परमया च सः || ६-५९-११९
शत्रूणामप्रकम्प्योऽपि लघुत्वमगमत्कपेः |  This is the verse I am referring to. Occurs in both critical edition and southern recension. Note the word bhakti in this verse.

Comment: @Satya yes, that verse is a likely interpolation as it does not occur in the critical edition.

Comment: @Satya: I am neither a Jnani nor I consider you to be an ignorant person.  :-).  I know that my answer may hurt the sentiments, linked to Bhakti oriented thinking, of many people.  However, I can say that neither I have interest in demeaning the character of Sri Rama nor am I inclined to elevate the character of Sri Hanuman.  I have been studying Valmiki Ramayana from 2010 onwards.  In fact it has become a passion to me.  My favourite characters are Sita, Sri Rama and Sri Hanuman.

Comment: @Satya: Having said so, it is my firm belief, emanated out of my passionate research on Ramayana , that Sage Valmiki never thought to project Sri Rama as an incarnation of Vishnu.  The whole problem arose due to projecting Sri Rama as an incarnation of Vishnu. Anyways, you have a choice to ignore my opinions and answers.  Regards.

Comment: Let Rama be mere mortal human, how fair it is to attribute that ego damage thing to Rama? I have no problem with you saying hanuma is not a devotee of Rama and who kniws Brahman becknes Brahman. Also your answer sounds Rama had his glory just because Hanuman let him have his share of glory.

Comment: @idol worshipper. Could you please let me know what were the reasons for critical edition to remove this verse? If mentioned in any footnotes or such in the critical edition. Sometimes people intrepret things in contradicting fashion themselves and decide some portions are interpolations/ some texts are later works etc., Anyways that's not a problem if any vedantin quoted it before 15h century,should look for that.

Comment: @Satya Sorry, I dont know the reasons. But I can guess that the reason is most likely textual - verse not being present in many manuscripts of Ramayana.

Comment: @Satya It is quite common for people here to elevate their favorite god(s) and/or belittle other gods. I suggest you dont take such things seriously.

Comment: @Satya Here is an equivalent verse that Rama quotes to Ravana (which is also present in the critical edition) - यदीन्द्रवैवस्वतभास्करान्वा |
स्वयमुभवैश्वानरशंकरान्वा |
गमिष्यसि त्वं दशधा दिशो वा |
तथापि मे नाद्य गतो विमोक्ष्यसे || ६-५९-१३०  It essentially says Ravana will not be spared by Rama even if the former seeks refuge with Indra, Brahma, Shiva etc.

Comment: @idol worshipper. //verse not being present in many manuscripts of Ramayan//  If this is the real reason I have no problem to assume it as an interpolation,not otherwise. Thanks for that other verse.

Answer (score 1):

According to Shiv Puran it is said that "After the samudra manthan, Lord Vishnu is his avatar as Mohini(enchatress) was distributing amruta to the gods by fooling the demons. Lord shiva was attracted by the beauty of Mohini avatar of Lord vishnu so lord Shiva released his seed on to the ground. 
The Saptarishis or seven sages passing near by with the permission of lord shiva placed Shiva’s seed inside the womb of Anjani, who was praying to Lord Shiva to get a child.
So this is probably the reason according to our scriptures why lord hanuman is considered as incarnation of lord shiva and his unflinching and natural devotion to lord rama(vishnu incarnate).
And also according to Vishnu Puran in BR Chopra serial it is mentioned that Lord Shiva wishes to serve Lord Vishnu and so he incarnates as lord hanuman.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question. I know Shiva loves Vishnu and Vishnu loves Shiva. But Hanuman doesn't know that he is avatar of Shiva. My Question is what made Hanuman to become Devotee of Rama? It would be better if one can explain from Ramayana. Also some versions say that seed was born as HariHara.

Comment: @AnilKumar The seed which was born as harihara or ayappa was a different one where lord vishnu rescues lord shiva from bhasmasur and lord shiva requests lord vishnu to display his mohini avatar again.

Then Lord vishnu he displays it when time comes, so ayyappa was born from Lord Vishnu(mohini avatar) and Lord Shiva to kill demon mahishi(according to SB), here ayyappa directly conceived by union of power of Vishnu and Shiva. But in the case of lord hanuman lord shiva's seed was transferred to womb of Anjani Devi.

Comment: @AnilKumar This site might clear your doubts to an extent it presented another view to the birth of hanuman http://jayahanuman.org/jayahanuman/history.htm

Comment: First of all this is folkore. Second of all Lord Ayyappa was born from this union. You really need to do your fact checking.

Answer (score 1):

All this began when Narad was attracted by a princess on the earth and was eager to marry her. The whole story is mentioned in [here](http://www.shreemaa.org/story-narada-curses-vishnu/). While in the end Narad cursed Vishnu for losing your beloved, and endure the pains of separation from her by which was the birth of Rama to be taken in future and then Shiva said that I will be having the birth as a face of monkey same as Narad and serve Vishnu at that point of time. Also you can see the full episode of [Shiv Mahapuran Episode 13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsLuIxq0Szk)

Comment: You should cite some scriptural-reference. TV shows are usually not considered reliable. Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange!

Answer (score 1):

Hanuman was well knowledge as he has knowledge of veda, vedangas, vedant.
So he somehow knew the actual truth of bhagwan shri Ramchandra.

**श्रीनाथो जानकीनाथो अभेदः परमात्मनि।
तथापि मम् सर्वस्वम् रामो राजीवलोचनः।।**

(Hanuman natak)

Hanumanji says:-
Narayan and shri Ram are indifferent from paramtma, but still, rajivlochan Shri Ramchandra is my everything.

How did he came to know the actual reality of shri Ram?

**ब्रह्मा विष्णु महेशाद्याः सत्यन्ते चिरंजीविनः।
सर्वेऽपि विभवाशक्ता यतोऽहम् विभवात् परः।।**

(~ hanuman samhita)

ब्रह्मा, विष्णु, महेश आदि देवगण ये सब चिंरजीवी है पर ऐश्वर्य से अशक्त हैं, पर मैं (हनुमान)वैभव के पार हो गया।

Brahma, Vishnu and Mahadeva and other devas are chiranjivi but are attached to opulence (as tridevas and other  are vibhuti/Guna avtar of shri Ram) but hanuman is beyond opulence